# How to send STDIN twice to Popen process, each time with EOF?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdin, popen, eof

I have this part of a code:

```py
for stdin in stdins:
    p.stdin.write(stdin)
```

which writes string `stdin` to process `p`'s STDIN.

The challenge is: the process `p` expects to see EOF before it goes to next STDIN.

With the loop above, the problem is that subsequent `p.stdin.write(stdin)` will be considered by the process `p` as input of the 1st STDIN input collection.  Because, as said earlier, `p` expect to see an EOF before moving to subsequent fields.

So, **my question is:**  how to solve this problem in Python?  The process needs to see something like:

```py
for stdin in stdins:
    p.stdin.write(stdin)
    p.stdin.send_eof()
```

**Constraints:** solution must not use pexpect.

Comment: That's a broken design. It should take two file name arguments or something if it expects input twice.

Comment: It cannot for security reasons.  The input is sensitive and must not touch the disk.  Specifically the 1st input is a password, and the 2nd input is plaintext (to be encrypted).

Comment: Why is it a broken design, though?  You made me curious.

Comment: have u tried `p.stdin.write('\n')`?

Comment: @LiorCohen - won't work.  Any way for sending EOF?  Is this a Python limitation?  Or is it a concept limitation?

Comment: Well, because there can only be one end (we call the other end "start").

Comment: Despite the rudeness, I tend to agree with @tripleee. Using EOF as a field separator in the standard input stream sounds awkward, what's the rationale behind that?
Is the `p` process under your control?

Comment: Or perhaps you can use a delimiter, or if the password is always exactly one line, just use that fact to partition the input into the password and the rest. If you use a delimiter, requiring the password to not contain the delimiter is brittle but probably workable in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EOF is not a character, it just means there is no more data to read.

As such I don't believe what you're after is possible in Python or most other languages.

Comment: I know.  Didn't say it's a character.  Why is it not possible to send such information that there is no more data to read?

Comment: Technically it should be possible because the OS can do it - ie when you do `ctrl + D`. I assume there was historically no need to add such a feature to a language. You could try to work around it, perhaps by closing `p.stdin.close()`? But for sure you can't _send_ it.

Comment: Yes closing is valid.  But, how to re-open `p.stdin` after closing it?

Comment: Really don't know, but you peaked my interest I'll be following this question

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem when I try to make a asynchronous render in python with several subprocess, which need to communicate with the main process in low delay.

When I use `subprocess.popen()` with `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`, I found that the subprocess can't get any content until `stdin.close()` happen or the main process exit, both sending an EOF signal but making the PIPE disposable. Surely I tried `stdin.writelines()`, `stdin.flush()`, `pickle.dump()` etc, but none of them worked.

But there is a way to repeatedly communicate with subprocess with **NumPy**.

[ndarray.tofile](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) can directly send an array to a file object. Although the document declare that it is ***equivalent to file.write(a.tobytes())***, it make sense indeed. I'm confused until I read this in the end of the doc page:

> When fid is a file object, array contents are directly written to the file, **bypassing the file object’s write method**. As a result, tofile cannot be used with files objects supporting compression (e.g., GzipFile) or file-like objects that do not support fileno() (e.g., BytesIO).

Actually, I think it is `file.write()`'s fault. Any function with calls `write()` method is inevitably unable to send EOF, unless we bypass the `write()` method, which is impossible without using some C extensions like NumPy.

To send general data throuth the PIPE now comes to two ways:

1. NumPy support `dtype=object`, which means you can pack your message into an object array directly. See also [numpy.lib.format](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html#module-numpy.lib.format).

   > Stores object arrays, i.e. arrays containing elements that are arbitrary Python objects. Files with object arrays are not to be mmapable, but can be read and written to disk.
2. You can state a Struct as a dtype to pack your message if it has a regular pattern, which is my situation. Here is my example.

   ```py
   task = np.dtype([(  "index",  np.uint8         ),
                    (   "text",  np.unicode_, 128 ),
                    (  "color",  np.uint8,    2   ),
                    (   "size",  np.uint8         )])
   for i in range(123):
       np.empty(1, dtype=task).tofile(s.stdin)  # s is the subprocess' name.
       time.sleep(1)
   ```

   Then I successfully got the message in the subprocess 123 times separately.

   <sup>I really hope this can help you. Because it takes me nearly 4 days to find this solution. I was almost considering to use a real file on disk to accomplish the communication between processes — which is supposed to be slower — but thanks to NumPy, my debugging finally comes to an end...</sup>

---

Plus, I think `np.save()` make no sense to send EOF. You can try this in a python console.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import sys
>>> a = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
>>> a.tofile(sys.stdout.buffer)
... some garbled characters ...
>>> a.tofiler(sys.stdout)
... some garbled characters ...
>>> np.save(sys.stdout.buffer, a)
... some garbled characters ...
>>> np.save(sys.stdout, a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in save
  ...
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

The reason is that `sys.stdout.buffer.write()` accept **bytes** parameter while `sys.stdout.write()` accept **str**. So using array.tofile write `sys.stdout` didn't cause any error reveal that it didn't called `write()` method while `np.save()` did. This raise a problem that it seems `np.fromfile` doesn't support `dtype=object` mode. Feel sorry about that. Maybe it's really hard to transfer dynamic typed data through processes through a pipe, but I've heard that inside `ctype` module there's some way to share RAM between processes, which may be of some help.

<sub>*Mention that I failed to run the script above in the terminal **(io.UnsupportedOperation: seek)**, but it runs well in PyCharm's python console. I have no idea about it. Maybe PyCharm's python console actually has a proxy of sys.stdin too.*</sub>

<sup>Plus, it seems `subprocess.PIPE` has a maximum buffer size, so transfering rendered images is impossible. As my experimental result, dividing them into blocks dosen't help.</sup>